# webpack syntax error is occuered in ReactDom.render()

Tags: webpack

error message is this

```
ERROR in ./client.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\react_game_prac2\client.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (5:64)

  3 |
  4 | const WordRelay = require('./WordRelay');
> 5 | ReactDom.render(<WordRelay /> , document.querySelector(selectors:'#root'));
```

code is this

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDom = require('react-dom');

const WordRelay = require('./WordRelay');
ReactDom.render(<WordRelay /> , document.querySelector(selectors:'#root'));
```

webpackcongig.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    name:'wordrelay-setting',
    mode:'development',
    devtool:'eval',
    resolve:{
        extensions:['.js','.jsx']
    },
    entry:{
        app:['./client']
    }, // 입력
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets:['@babel/preset-env','@babel/preset-react'],
                    plugins:['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
                },
            }
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path:path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename:'app.js'
    },  // 출력
};
```

after npm run dev error is occuered
But I can not find the cause of the error.

I tried to find it hard, but it is difficult to find it with my skills.
Excuse me, but thank you if you take a look.

git hub url : https://github.com/hyunsokstar/react_game_prac2

and

I get an error if I change it like this

```
ReactDom.render(<WordRelay /> , document.querySelector({ selectors: '#root' });
```

```
ERROR in ./client.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\react_game_prac2\client.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (5:78)

  3 |
  4 | const WordRelay = require('./WordRelay');
> 5 | ReactDom.render(<WordRelay /> , document.querySelector({ selectors: '#root' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid JavaScript: `document.querySelector(selectors:'#root')`

Functions can accept plain objects, which may be what you were going for here, e.g.

```
document.querySelector({ selectors: '#root' })
```

But in this case, `querySelector` accepts a [single string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Parameters) (`'#root'` in your case).

Comment: thanks for answer but

ERROR in ./client.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\react_game_prac2\client.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (5:78)

  3 |
  4 | const WordRelay = require('./WordRelay');
> 5 | ReactDom.render(<WordRelay /> , document.querySelector({ selectors: '#root' });

Comment: thanks i tiried it but it's not answer thank you for reply ^^;

Comment: When I clone your repository and make the change I suggested, the build is successful. Also, your usage of querySelector is still incorrect - `document.querySelector('#root')` is what you need.

Comment: it's work ~!  Thank you for your useful answer  Due to my basic mistake download + execute ^^ ;; very very Thank you ~!